# In MySQL, how to use a subquery to a left join statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, clause

I tried to count how many new tuples are in a subset of t2 as compared to t1 by

```
SELECT
  COUNT(t2.id)
FROM (
  (SELECT id, col1 FROM t2 WHERE col2=0 AND col3=0) AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    t1
  ON
    t.id=t1.id
)
WHERE
  t1.id IS NULL;
```

The subset is defined by

```
(SELECT id, col1 FROM t2 WHERE col2=0 AND col3=0) AS t
```

But the above program doesn't seem to work, issuing errors.

Comment: Change the first line to count(t.id) . . . the t2 alias is in the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to enclose the `FROM` clause in `()`.  You are referencing `t2.id` in your aggregate `COUNT()`, but your `SELECT` list will only produce `t.id` from the subquery that encapsulates `t2`. This version addresses the source of your errors:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(t.id) AS idcount
FROM 
  (SELECT id, col1 FROM t2 WHERE col2=0 AND col3=0) AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON t.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

#### However:

Since your subquery is actually pretty simple, I believe it isn't necessary at all. The whole thing can be done with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  /* The equivalent of COUNT(*) in this context */
  COUNT(t2.id) AS idcount
FROM
  t2 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE
  t1.id IS NULL
  AND (t2.col2 = 0 AND t2.col3 = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you don't want to do COUNT(t.id)?  t2 is in a subquery and is not available to the main query only t and t1 are available.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the alias.  You have:

```
select count(t2.id)
```

But, t2 is defined in the subquery, so it is out of scope.

You want:

```
select count(t.id)
```